How does $\int_{-1}^1 (1-t)^{u-1}(1+t)^{u}\,dt$ become $2\int_{0}^1 (1-t^2)^{u-1}\,dt$?
A text (not one with any problems or questions) has the following
$$\int_{-1}^1 (1-t)^{u-1}(1+t)^{u}\,dt=2\int_{0}^1 (1-t^2)^{u-1}\,dt    $$
but they do not explain the derivation. I cannot see how they derive the equality.
I transform it to
$$\int_{-1}^1 (1-t^2)^{u-1}(1+t)\,dt $$
but seems I am getting nowhere with that.
I would hate to think one would have to use trig. substitutions involving arc sin or arc cos etc. or transform it to something in contour integration and using residues etc. and i don't see how that would work either.
Can anyone derive their transformation?

$$\int_{-1}^1 (1-t^2)^{u-1}(1+t)dt=\int_{-1}^1 (1-t^2)^{u-1}dt+\int_{-1}^1 (1-t^2)^{u-1}tdt=2\int_0^1(1-t^2)^{u-1}dt+0$$
The last integral is zero (the integrand is odd, and the interval is symmetric), and the first integrand is even.

He does equate the transformation to the integral 0 to 1, rhs of equality, to $B(1/2,u)$ where B is the beta function and i can derive that but that doesn't help me with the original equality posted.

@user158293 Svyatoslav has answered for you. Maybe as a first step we realise $(1-t)^{u-1}(1+t)^u=(1-t)^{u-1}(1+t)^{u-1}(1+t)=(1-t^2)^{u-1}(1+t)$

Oh how ridiculous of me when said that i was getting nowhere with $\int_{-1}^1 (1-t^2)^{u-1}(1+t)dt $ i actually had it right there - obvious the ....t... part of (1+t)... in the integral. gave an odd integral which was 0

We map $t\mapsto-t$,
$
\int_{-1}^0 \frac{(1-t^2)^u}{1-t}\,dt =\int_0^1\frac{(1-t^2)^u}{1+t}\,dt.
$
Then,
$
\int_0^1\frac{(1-t^2)^u}{1-t}\,dt+\int_0^1\frac{(1-t^2)^u}{1+t}\,dt=2\int_0^1\frac{(1-t^2)^u}{1-t^2}\,dt.
$
